# Facebook pending authorization exception while updating status from android

Tags: android, facebook, sdk, fragment, onactivityresult

Hi I have to publish my status from an activity that is hosting a fragment and on using application for first time and after logging into application I get an exception when I try to update the status . I get this exception.

"Session: an attempt was made to request new permissions for a session that has a pending request."

Here is my code for Fragment

```
      import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.provider.Settings.Secure;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.carfrenzy.activities.FeedsActivity;
import com.carfrenzy.activities.SelectCarActivity;
import com.carfrenzy.activities.TourActivity;
import com.carfrenzy.activities.UserProfileActivity;
import com.carfrenzy.app.R;
import com.carfrenzy.beans.CFConstants;
import com.carfrenzy.beans.UserProfileInfo;
import com.carfrenzy.ui.ProgressBarDialog;
import com.carfrenzy.webservices.WebHttpServicesManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookRequestError;
import com.facebook.HttpMethod;
import com.facebook.Request;
import com.facebook.RequestAsyncTask;
import com.facebook.Response;
import com.facebook.Session;
import com.facebook.SessionState;
import com.facebook.UiLifecycleHelper;
import com.facebook.widget.LoginButton;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;
import com.turbomanage.httpclient.AsyncCallback;
import com.turbomanage.httpclient.HttpResponse;

public class MainFragment extends Fragment
{
    private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;

    String accessToken = "";
    SharedPreferences mprefs;
    String mTutorial = "";
    static Context context;
    static Context mcontext;

    Button login;
    EditText etemail, etpass;

    private static final List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("publish_actions");
    private static final List<String> EMAIL_PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("email");
    private static final String PENDING_PUBLISH_KEY = "pendingPublishReauthorization";
    private static boolean pendingPublishReauthorization = false;
    final String pushNotificationToken = "";
    String android_id = "";
    String pushToken = "";
    private static final String TAG = "MainFragment";
    ImageView iemail;


    Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(this, Arrays.asList("email"));

    LoginButton authButton = null;


    //private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog = null;

    Handler handler;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        context = getActivity().getBaseContext();
        mcontext = getActivity();

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.startup, container, false);
        etemail = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etUser);
        etpass = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etPass);
        login = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.bLoginNew);
        login.setEnabled(true);
        authButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.authButton);
        authButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.logo_facebook);
        authButton.setFragment(this);
        authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("email"));

        View viewp = inflater.inflate(R.layout.user_mycar_home, container, false);
        /***************/
        android_id = Secure.getString(getActivity().getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);

        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                                 {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                if (etemail.getText().toString().equals("") || etpass.getText().toString().equals(""))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Please enter your email address and password to login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else if (etpass.getText().toString().length() < 6)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Password is invalid. It should be atleast 6 characters", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else if (etpass.getText().toString().length() > 5)
                {
                    //pushToken=getRegistrationId(context);
                    //Log.i("Audit", pushToken);

                    //mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(),
                    //  "Cruising...","", true);
                    //mProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);

                    final ProgressBarDialog dialogBar = new ProgressBarDialog(getActivity(), "Cruising...");
                    //
                    dialogBar.show();

                    pushToken=   mprefs.getString("PROPERTY_REG_ID", "");
                    Log.i("Audit", pushToken);
                    new WebHttpServicesManager(context).signInWithEmail(etemail.getText().toString(), etpass.getText().toString(), android_id.toString(), pushToken.toString(), new AsyncCallback()
                                                                        {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(HttpResponse httpResponse)
                        {
                            dialogBar.dismiss();
                            if (httpResponse != null && httpResponse.getStatus() == 200)
                            {

                                //mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                                String responseString = WebHttpServicesManager.decompress(httpResponse.getBody());

                                JSONObject jsonResponse=null;
                                JSONObject status;

                                JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
                                JsonObject o = (JsonObject)parser.parse(responseString);
                                try
                                {
                                    if( o!=null && o.get("status").getAsString().equals("1"))
                                    {
                                        jsonResponse = new JSONObject(responseString);
                                        JSONObject response = jsonResponse.getJSONObject("response");
                                        String active1 = response.getString("activeSalt");
                                        mprefs.edit().putString("activeSalt", active1).commit();
                                        Boolean tour = mprefs.getBoolean(TourActivity.SharedPrefKey, false);

                                        if (tour)
                                        {
                                            // Intent intent = new
                                            // Intent(context,TourActivity.class);
                                            // startActivity(intent);
                                            //                                      tourDon();
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        jsonResponse = new JSONObject(responseString);
                                        JSONObject response = jsonResponse.getJSONObject("response");
                                        Toast.makeText(context, "Error:"+ response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }

                                }
                                catch (JSONException e)
                                {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                String isTutorial = mprefs.getString("isTutorial", "");

                                //                              if(isTutorial.equalsIgnoreCase("1"))
                                //                              {
                                //                                  Intent in = new Intent(context, SelectCarActivity.class);
                                //                                  in.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                                //                              login.setEnabled(false);
                                //                                  startActivity(in);
                                //                                  getActivity().finish();
                                //                              }
                                //                              else
                                //                              {
                                Intent in = new Intent(context, UserProfileActivity.class);
                                in.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                                login.setEnabled(false);
                                startActivity(in);
                                //                                  Log.i("SignIn", "Success");
                                getActivity().finish();
                                return;
                                //}
                            }
                            else if (httpResponse !=null && httpResponse.getStatus()==401)
                            {
                                //                              AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).setTitle("Oops").setMessage("Cannot connect to server please Try again with valid email and password!").setNeutralButton("OK", null);
                                //                              AlertDialog alert1 = alert.create();
                                //                              alert1.show();
                                String responseString = WebHttpServicesManager.decompress(httpResponse.getBody());
                                //JSONObject jsonResponse=null;

                                JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
                                JsonObject o = (JsonObject)parser.parse(responseString);
                                String message = o.get("response").getAsString();
                                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(mcontext).setTitle("Error").setMessage(" " +message ).setNeutralButton("OK", null);
                                alert.show();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(mcontext).setTitle("Oops").setMessage("Cannot connect to server. Please Try again!" ).setNeutralButton("OK", null);
                                alert.show();
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(Exception e, int errorCode)
                        {
                            super.onError(e, errorCode);
                            //mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                            dialogBar.dismiss();
                            if (errorCode == CFConstants.INTERNET_NOT_AVAILABLE)
                            {
                                //                              AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).setTitle("No Internet Connectivity").setMessage("Please Check Your Internet Connection and Try again!").setNeutralButton("OK", null);
                                //                              AlertDialog alert1 = alert.create();
                                //                              alert1.show();
                                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(mcontext, "Please Check Your Internet Connection and Try again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                                toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                                toast.show();
                            }
                            Log.i("SignIn", "Error");
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(org.apache.http.HttpResponse httpResponse)
                        {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            //mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                            dialogBar.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            pendingPublishReauthorization =
            savedInstanceState.getBoolean(PENDING_PUBLISH_KEY, false);
        }

        return view;
    }

    private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception)
    {
        if (pendingPublishReauthorization &&
            state.equals(SessionState.OPENED_TOKEN_UPDATED)) {
            pendingPublishReauthorization = false;
            publishStory();
        }

        if (state.isOpened())
        {
            if (pendingPublishReauthorization && state.equals(SessionState.OPENED_TOKEN_UPDATED))
            {
                pendingPublishReauthorization = false;
                publishStory();
            }

            else if (!pendingPublishReauthorization)
            {
                try
                {
                    Log.i("Audit", "Logged in...");
                    Log.i("fb2", accessToken);


                    // Check for email permissions
                    List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();
                    if (!isSubsetOf(EMAIL_PERMISSIONS, permissions))
                    {
                        session.requestNewReadPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);

                        return;
                    }

                    accessToken = session.getAccessToken();
                    UserProfileInfo.setAccessToken(accessToken);
                    pushToken=   mprefs.getString("PROPERTY_REG_ID", "");
                    facebookLogin(accessToken, pushToken);
                }

                catch(Exception e )
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        else if (state.isClosed())
        {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Error: Can't Login through Facebook! Please try again later!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


    }

    private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback()
    {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception)
    {
    onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
}
};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), callback);
uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
mprefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("com.carfrenzy.app", getActivity().MODE_PRIVATE);
android_id = Secure.getString(getActivity().getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);
pushToken=   mprefs.getString("PROPERTY_REG_ID", "");
Boolean firstTour = mprefs.getBoolean(TourActivity.firstTimTour, false);
}

@Override
public void onResume()
{
super.onResume();
// For scenarios where the main activity is launched and user
// session is not null, the session state change notification
// may not be triggered. Trigger it if it's open/closed.
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
if (session != null && (session.isOpened() || session.isClosed()))
{
onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);
}

uiHelper.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
Log.v("in activity result of :::", "Main fragment");
uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
//Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult((Activity) context, requestCode, resultCode, data);

Log.i("Audit", "I am here in Result of fragment");
}

@Override
public void onPause()
{
super.onPause();
uiHelper.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
super.onDestroy();
uiHelper.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
outState.putBoolean(PENDING_PUBLISH_KEY, pendingPublishReauthorization);
uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

private void facebookLogin(final String accessToken, final String pushToken)
{
String mAccessToken = UserProfileInfo.getAccessToken();
Log.i("Audit", mAccessToken);
//      final ProgressBarDialog dialogBar = new ProgressBarDialog(context, "Cruising...");
//      dialogBar.show();
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(mcontext, "Fetching data from Facebook Servers! This may take few seconds!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
toast.show();
//Toast.makeText(context, "Fetching data from Facebook Servers! This may take few seconds!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
new WebHttpServicesManager(getActivity()).signInFacebook("1", accessToken.toString(), android_id.toString(), pushToken.toString(), new AsyncCallback()
{
public void onComplete(HttpResponse httpResponse)
{
//  dialogBar.dismiss();

if (httpResponse != null && httpResponse.getStatus() == 200)
{
String responseString = WebHttpServicesManager.decompress(httpResponse.getBody());
Log.e("SignUp", " Server data : " + httpResponse.getBodyAsString());
JSONObject jsonResponse = null;
JSONObject status;

JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonObject o = (JsonObject) parser.parse(responseString);
try
{
if (o != null && o.get("status").getAsString().equals("1"))
{
jsonResponse = new JSONObject(responseString);
JSONObject response = jsonResponse.getJSONObject("response");
String active1 = response.getString("activeSalt");
mprefs.edit().putString("activeSalt", active1).commit();
mTutorial = response.getString("userTutorial");
mprefs.edit().putString("userTutorial", mTutorial);
String suggestedTour = response.getString("isSuggestedTour");
mprefs.edit().putString("suggestedTour", suggestedTour);

}
else
{
jsonResponse = new JSONObject(responseString);
JSONObject response = jsonResponse.getJSONObject("response");
Toast.makeText(context, "Error:" + response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
}
catch (JSONException e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
}

if (mTutorial.toString().equals("1"))
{
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SelectCarActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("fbAccessToken", accessToken);
getActivity().startActivity(intent);
Log.i("SignInFacebook", "Success");
}
else if (mTutorial.toString().equals("0"))
{
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), FeedsActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("fbAccessToken", accessToken);
getActivity().startActivity(intent);
}
}
else if (httpResponse != null && httpResponse.getStatus() == 401)
{
//new AlertDialog.Builder(context).setTitle("Cannot connect to server").setMessage("We cannot connect to server! Please try again Later!").setNeutralButton("OK", null).show();
//      dialogBar.dismiss();
Toast.makeText(context, "We cannot connect to server! Please try again Later!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}

@Override
public void onError(Exception e, int errorCode)
{
super.onError(e, errorCode);
//  dialogBar.dismiss();
if (errorCode == CFConstants.INTERNET_NOT_AVAILABLE)
{
//new AlertDialog.Builder(context).setTitle("No Internet Connectivity").setMessage("Please Check Your Internet Connection and Try again!").setNeutralButton("OK", null).show();
//  dialogBar.dismiss();
Toast.makeText(context, "Please Check Your Internet Connection and Try again!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
Log.i("SignUp", "error");
}

@Override
public void onComplete(org.apache.http.HttpResponse httpResponse)
{
//      dialogBar.dismiss();
}
});
}



public static void publishStory()
{
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

if (session != null)
{
// Check for publish permissions
List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();
if (!isSubsetOf(PERMISSIONS, permissions))
{
pendingPublishReauthorization = true;
Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session
.NewPermissionsRequest((Activity) mcontext, PERMISSIONS);
session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
return;
}
final ProgressBarDialog dialogBar = new ProgressBarDialog(mcontext, "Cruising...");
//
dialogBar.show();
Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
postParams.putString("name", "Motoqlik");
postParams.putString("caption", "You can now Look out for road users via motoqlik");
postParams.putString("description", "A smart new way to look out for road users! Look out for one another on roads and car park!");
postParams.putString("link", "http://www.motoqlik.com/");
postParams.putString("picture", "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-frc3/c57.33.414.414/s160x160/972186_590988330944636_1055194609_n.png");

Request.Callback callback = new Request.Callback()
{
public void onCompleted(Response response)
{
dialogBar.dismiss();
if (response != null)
{
JSONObject graphResponse = response.getGraphObject().getInnerJSONObject();
String postId = null;
try
{
postId = graphResponse.getString("id");
Log.i(TAG, "postId " + postId);
Toast.makeText(context, "Shared on your profile"+ postId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//  AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).setTitle("Success").setMessage("Shared on your wall" + postId).setNeutralButton("OK", null);
//alert.show();
}
catch (JSONException e)
{
Log.i(TAG, "JSON error " + e.getMessage());
}
FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
if (error != null)
{
Toast.makeText((Activity) context, error.getErrorMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).setTitle("Sharing Error").setMessage("Cannot connect to facebook Servers!" + error.getErrorMessage()).setNeutralButton("OK", null);
//alert.show();
}
else
{
}
}
else
{
Toast.makeText(context, "Could not Connect to Facebook!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//  AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).setTitle("Sharing Error").setMessage("Cannot connect to facebook Servers!").setNeutralButton("OK", null);
//alert.show();
}
}
};

Request request = new Request(session, "me/feed", postParams, HttpMethod.POST, callback);

RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
task.execute();
}

}

private static boolean isSubsetOf(Collection<String> subset, Collection<String> superset)
{
for (String string : subset)
{
if (!superset.contains(string))
{
return false;
}
}
return true;
}

}
```

The publishStory() method is the actual method for post on my wall. This method is being called from host activity. And The UILifeCycleHelper handling is done in onActivityResult of fragment, but the fragment's onActivityResult is not being called after publish story. This only happens when user uses the application for first time and tries to publish to facebook. 
If he logout and login again , then he can post successfully and exception is not raised. 
Any kind of help would be appreciated ,

Thanks and Regards,
Munazza

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey use this library instead to do facebook authorization.

https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook